# Python exporting with Pyinstaller with multiple folders

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller

I've made an app with the following structure:

[image]

It is an app where you insert data, it adds it to the database (.db inside database folder), and it generates an excel file that is exported to the /excels/ folder using an excel template located inside of the /plantilla/ folder.

I need that the exported app has access to those exported excel files and template ones, also to the database file as it will go to a local network folder.

I have tried exporting it using the .spec file with the next code:

```
    added_files = [
    ( 'database/', 'data' ),
    ( 'excels/', 'data' ),
    ( 'formularios/', 'data'),
    ( 'imagenes/', 'data'),
    ( 'model/', 'data'),
    ( 'plantilla/', 'data'),
    ( 'theme/', 'data'),
    ( 'util/', 'data' )
]
```

The issue is that when I got to the /dist/ folder the structure is the following:

[image]

[image]

When I open the .exe file, it opens a window and closes quickly but I managed to take a screenshot of it:
[image]

Which is weird because I have included the folder in the added files command...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correct, you are trying to add additional data directories/files in your app which you want to access after making the build. To do that you can update the spec file to add additional files by updating "datas" in Analysis. Like this:

```
datas=[('current_file_path/filename.txt', '.')]
```

Here, the first argument is path to file or folder where the current data is present and the second argument is where you want to place them after the build is done.

And after the build, you can access this data using

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'filename.txt')
```

As we placed the files and folder relative to the new exe directory, you need to access it using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` in path. So if you change the destination path from `.` to `data` you can access it using

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'filename.txt')
```

Comment: Okey perfect I understand it better and I think that should be the way to go.

The only issue is that my main.py is located at the root folder of the project but then it loads a .py file within the /formularios/ folder so whenever I get the os.path.dirname(__file__) I get that folder so if I join it with "data" to find the txt file, it  creates something like this:

"'C:\\Users\\XX\\XX\\App\\formularios\\data\\filename.txt'

But really the file is located outside of that folder... it would be:

"'C:\\Users\\XX\\XX\\App\\data\\filename.txt'

Comment: You can get the C:\\Users\\XX\\XX\\App\\ folder by just using `os.path.dirname` again on the directory name you are getting. For ex, if you are getting C:\\Users\\XX\\XX\\App\\formularios\\ as the `directory_path`, then you can do `os.path.dirname(directory_path)` to get the directory you need and then join it with the rest of "data" folder and filename. Hope that helps.

Comment: awesome that does work (I had to change the code a little bit to check if the app is being ran as a bundle or not because if it does I don't have to do that or otherwise it will break the '_internal' folder structure. Thanks!